# Rails: use button_to for create action of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Why can I not get my button_to to specify the create action of my controller rather than show

I have tried numerous times to add :action => "create" and other such things to the button_to parameters

```
<%= button_to "subscribe", subscription_path(feed_url: @feed.feed_url)%>
```

do I need to specify a create route in my routes.rb? if so how should I go about that?

When used the way that line is, I get this error on load:

Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"subscriptions", :feed_url=>"http://foo.com/rss"}

in routes.rb I have this as the only reference to subscriptions.

```
  resource :subscriptions
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `subscriptons_path`, not `subscription_path`.

`subscription_path` is for showing a specific subscription.
`subscriptions_path` is for showing all subscriptions (via a GET request) or creating new subscriptions (via a POST request).

```
<%= button_to "subscribe", subscriptions_path(feed_url: @feed.feed_url, :method => :post)%>
```